# Django - User Billing Platforms / Middleware, i.e., Tracking Expenses and Charges

Tags: python, django, payment-processing, billing

I am writing a webapp and I would like to start charging my users.  What are the recommended billing platforms for a python/Django webapp?

I would like something that keeps track of my users' purchase history, can elegantly handle subscription purchases, a la carte items, coupon codes, and refunds, makes it straightforward to generate invoices/receipts, and can easily integrate with most payment processors. Extra points if it comes with a fancy admin interface.

I found this [django-billing project](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/django-billing), are there any others? Also, do you rely on your payment processor to handle these tasks or do you do all of them yourself?

*Note: I am not asking what payment processors to use, but rather what middleware/libraries one should run on their webapp itself.*

Comment: That's a tall order.  I implemented a portion of what you're asking for at work but it's closed-source.  When I started on the project a year ago I couldn't find anything worth building on.

Answer (score 1):

The **[koalixcrm](https://github.com/scaphilo/koalixcrm)** is perhaps something you could start with.

It offers some of your required functionality. Still it is in a prealpha stage but it already provides PDF export for Invoices and Quotes, there is already one included plugin for subscriptions.

also try the **[demo](https://github.com/scaphilo/koalixcrm/wiki)**

As i am the developer of the koalixcrm im very interested to work with you - perhaps we can merge our projects.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear why Django Community hasn't come up a with complete billing system or at least a generic one to start working on.

There's many packages that can be used for getting an idea how to implement such platform:

https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/payment-processing/